# Doxygen Highlight Parameter in Pre-condition

Tags: doxygen

I have a doxygen header for a function as follows:

```
/** Some description.

    @param[in]  grid1      First grid
    @param[in]  grid2      Second grid

    @pre grid1 and grid2 must be of the same dimensions
*/
```

I'd like `grid1` and `grid2` to be specially highlighted in the pre-conditions section of the generated documentations, since they are parameters. In my mind, I should be able to do something like

```
@pre #grid1 and #grid2 must be the same size
```

But this doesn't work.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be nice if `#` automatically linked to the function argument definition. However, I can't see anyway of doing this in the [automatic link generation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html) section of the doxygen manual.

Having looked at the documentation HTML source it seems that parameters seem to be simply styled as `strong` and with the class `paramname`. So something like

```
@pre <strong class="paramname">grid1</strong> and
    <strong class="paramname">grid2</strong> must be the same size.
```

should give you the results you want. Clearly this is overly verbose to write out each time. However, you should be able to define a [custom command](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html), say `\paramname`, to do this so you could just write

```
@pre \paramname{grid1} and \paramname{grid2} must be the same size.
```

**Edit**: This can be achieved with the configuration file alias

```
ALIASES += paramname{1}="<strong class="paramname">\1</strong>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Landed here looking for the answer, but found it elsewhere.

Use [`\p`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdp) to indicate that the next word is a function parameter.

And, of course, you can use `@` instead of `\`.

```
/** Some description.

    @param[in]  grid1      First grid
    @param[in]  grid2      Second grid

    @pre @p grid1 and @p grid2 must be of the same dimensions
*/
```

See Doxygen [Special Commands reference](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html).